# Configurable Product Values Error : If select Drop-Down values price change to "0"

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have set configurable products, if i select products selection its show "0",

[image]

Comment: have you done indexing after price update ?

Comment: @RahulSingh Yes i did

Comment: @RahulSingh May i know any other possibilities of error?

Comment: Are you Using any third party extension ?

Comment: @Pravin Yes, but how can i find which extension affect this function?